# Integration of Hibernate search with RabbitMQ for distributed backend

Tags: java, hibernate, jms, rabbitmq, hibernate-search

Has anyone integrated Hibernate Search index queuing with RabbitMQ instead or JMS or ActiveMQ.

We already use RabbitMQ as part of our application in several different areas. We don't want to introduce redundant software that we have to maintain further. What are some alternatives to that model?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You *might* have some luck using the apache QPid jms client with rabbitmq. It can be a challenge though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement a custom

```
org.hibernate.search.backend.spi.BackendQueueProcessor
```

(SPI stands for service programming interface: i.e. not exactly a public API but meant do define stable extension points)

Have a look at the JMS implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/tree/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/impl/jms), you will see you only have to:

- grab de serialization service
- serialize the queue of operations which is sent to you
- send it over to the queue

For the receiver side it's as simple:

- grab the deserialization service
- deserialize the queue
- forward it to the correct indexManager

Example: [full implementation is one method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/orm/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/impl/jms/AbstractJMSHibernateSearchController.java#L88).

Feel free to contribute it! We accept pull requests, you can also send incomplete proposals to discuss them on github (or you're welcome on the mailing lists).